# How to deploy on custom docker registry?

Tags: drone.io

I setup a simple go project and I wish to build and deploy a simple docker image to my private registry. 
This is my .drone.yml:

```
pipeline:   
  build:
    image: golang
    commands:
      - go build

  docker:
    image: plugins/docker
    username: xxxxxxxxxxx
    password: yyyyyyyyyyy
    repo: docker.mycompany.it:5000/drone/test
    tags: latest
    debug: true
```

But the plugins tries to connect and authenticate to docker registry.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using a custom registry you need to set the `registry` parameter in the plugin configuration [1]. The registry parameter is provided to the docker login command (e.g. `docker login gcr.io`)

Example configuration with custom registry:

```
pipeline:
  docker:
    image: plugins/docker
    repo: index.company.com/foo/bar
    registry: index.company.com
```

[1] source http://plugins.drone.io/drone-plugins/drone-docker/

Comment: ...and if your private registry is not secured with TLS you should also add the `insecure: true` parameter to the plugin configuration